# Difficulty updating a label inside a button callback

Tags: python, callback, tkinter, label, config

I'm new to both Tkinter and Python 3.3 and trying to develop a simple GUI. I have a label "statusLabel". When I click on the button, I want to update the value in the label in the button's callback, but I'm getting the error.

```
line 12, in reportCallback
    statusLabel.config(text="Thank you. Generating report...")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Below is my code

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

Label(root,text="Project folders. Include full paths. One project per line").pack()
Text(root,height=4).pack()
Label(root,text="Standard project subfolders. Include path from project.").pack()
Text(root,height=4).pack()

statusLabel = Label(root,text="Oh, hello.").pack()

def reportCallback():
    statusLabel.config(text="Thank you. Generating report...")

b = Button(root, text="Generate Report", command=reportCallback).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: may you should make your statusLabel global if you want to use it in a defined function (it's not defined in there -> NoneType)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
statusLabel = Label(root,text="Oh, hello.").pack()
```

`.pack()` returns `None`. Presumably, you want `statusLabel` to hold a reference to the `Label` object you just created.

Try this instead:

```
statusLabel = Label(root,text="Oh, hello.")
statusLabel.pack()
```

See, for instance, the trivial program in the first listing here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm